# I cannot change the background color of collection view programmatically

Tags: swift

I do not know why I cannot change the first screen programmatically. The first screen remains white even if I change the color of collection view background color. I need someone's help.

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        window = UIWindow()
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: PokemonController(collectionViewLayout: layout))
        window?.rootViewController = navController

        return true
    }
```

This is the code inside the Controller file. I deleted the default controller file.

```
class PokemonController: UICollectionViewController {
    //property
    //Init
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        configureViewComponent()

    }

    func configureViewComponent() {
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .white

        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .mainPink()
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: It would be good if you describe your problem in detail.

Comment: Use the [Xcode view debugger](https://sesamenotes.files.wordpress.com/2015/07/screen-shot-2015-07-22-at-8-03-32-am.png) to see which view causes the white appearance. For example there might be an additional layer that is on top of the views whose background colors you've already tried to change.

Comment: Can you clarify it a little? Did you create a new project in Xcode 11 and whenever you run it the screen remains white?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it like this

```
func configureViewComponent() {
    backgroundColor = .white

    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .mainPink()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this and let me know, if it works.

```
func configureViewComponent() {
        collectionView.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = .red

        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .mainPink()
    }
```